# angular controlvalueaccessor formgroup issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular controlvalueaccessor and getting data from child to parent, but I want to manipulate the data,

I am getting something like below code, contactInfo is my child component data,

```
{
 contactInfo: {workPhone: {phone: 495987, msg: 'me'}, mobilePhone: {phone: 495987, msg: 'me'}, fax: "90876655"},
 createdById: 707,
 email: "d@d.com",
 fax: "90876655"
}
```

but in payload, I have to send something like below

```
{
 workPhone: {phone: 495987, msg: 'me'},
 mobilePhone: {phone: 495987, msg: 'me'},
 fax: "90876655",
 createdById: 707,
 email: "d@d.com",
 fax: "90876655"
}
```

How can I do it, please help me.

Comment: `obj['workPhone'] = obj.contactInfo.workPhone; obj['mobilePhone'] = obj.contactInfo.mobilePhone; delete obj['contactInfo']` however this is very dirty, it's better if your formcontrols are already returning the data as you'd like it to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example:

```js
let data = {
 contactInfo: {workPhone: {phone: 495987, msg: 'me'}, mobilePhone: {phone: 495987, msg: 'me'}, fax: "90876655"},
 createdById: 707,
 email: "d@d.com",
 fax: "90876655"
};

let payload = {...data};
delete payload.contactInfo;
payload = {...data.contactInfo, ...payload};

console.log(payload);
```

Answer (score 0):

just use an auxiliar variable before send the data,e.g.

```
submit(form:FormGroup){
  if form.valid)
  {
    const dataSend={
      workPhone:form.value.contactInfo.workPhone
      mobilePhone:form.value.contactInfo.mobilePhone
      fax:form.value.fax,
      createdById:form.value.createdById,
      email:form.value.emai
    }
    this.myService.sendData(data);
  }
}
```